# Javascript works good only at localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ftp

please take a look , pictures cannot be loaded

[link]http://markizasklep.website.pl/altea/agency-index.html

when i start website at localhost there is everything ok, but when i start from my ftp server i think JavaScript doesn't work. I've checked size of paths (jpg - JPG , etc.) and it is not a reason i think. Have You got some ideas ?
To edit file i am using Dreamweaver ,maybe it is important ;)

Comment: your prettyPhoto plugin's javascript and css not found, fix this first.
I think you dont have upload it on your ftp

Comment: dude, http://markizasklep.website.pl/altea/js-plugin/pretty-photo/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js is not found, so you are resulting in error Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyPhoto' .  make sure about your path

Answer (score 0):

If you open the developer tools e.g. in chrome you will see that the browser doesn't find at least two files: `prettyPhoto.css` and `jquery.prettyPhoto.js`.
Try uploading them.

Answer (score 0):

First: **Next time provide smaller sample** :) and second You give 404 for jquery.prettyPhoto.js so reason is probably that you have this file on localhost but on on server.